# raspberry pi4 opencv and usb web camera python3 I had install opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi4, webcam-capture

in face recognition  I write below code but I still have problem that USB webcam could not open in new window I try to put -1 and 1 and it dose not work

```
import cv2
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cv2.namedWindow("press space to take a photo", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow("press space to take a photo", 500, 300)

img_counter = 0

while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    if not ret:
        print("failed to grab frame")
        break
    cv2.imshow("press space to take a photo", frame)
```

```
error message
 [ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-wheel-qd18ncao/opencv-python/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): cant open camera by index
failed to grab frame
```

Comment: do u test your camera installed correctly ? test it with `raspivid` command. after that try set another index in `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` like `cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)` or `2`

Comment: what if you specify the backend in videocapture? like `cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_V4L)`